# When I zoom GMaps custom markerview changes position

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers

I am working with Google maps, I have created custom marker view and set it to my marker

```
marker.iconView = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 198, height: 34))
```

Here my custom markerview

```
import UIKit
class CustomMarkerView: UIView {
    var logo = UIImage()
    var adress = UILabel()
    var price = UILabel()
    var icon_like = UIImage(named: "icon_like")
    var icon_direction = UIImage(named: "icon_direction")

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addCustomView()
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, logo: String, adress: String, price: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.logo = UIImage(named: logo)!
        self.adress.text = adress
        self.price.text = price
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView() {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bgMarkerView")!).cgColor
    }
}
```

All works okay until I start zooming the map. If I zoom it the marker view will change position, but the position coordinate doesn't change:

[image: Screenshot of marker position while zoomed out. Marker is to the left of the river.]

[image: Screenshot of marker position while zoomed in. Marker is now to the right of the river.]

i understand that it is the problem of view represent, because actually marker.position doesn't change, but as you can see on the screens visual it changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what google trying to do here is keeping the "anchor point" at the same coordinate. And by default the anchor point is the midpoint of the bottom bound of your custom `UIView`.

I see that what you are trying to do is showing a infoView. If this is the case, you can use the delegate method:

```
- (nullable UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

Comment: As far as i understand infoview is creates when i tap on the marker, but i need the marker is being like on screen without tapping

Comment: Yes thaks, maybe it will be better to use infowindow in my case, because all marker view always center by the position.